# How do I secure static files exposed via httpd using Keycloak?

Tags: apache, keycloak

Here is my setup:

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine
COPY ./static-files/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

I ran the image and can access the files at *localhost:3000/static-files/*

I also have a Keycloak(12.0.1) running at *localhost:8080/auth* (I have already created all its properties like Realm, client and users etc.)

***My requirement is something like that:***

Whenever I access *localhost:3000/static-files/* I should be redirected to Keycloak *localhost:8080/auth*  for authentication and after successful login, I should be able to view static files available at *localhost:3000/static-files/*

**Basically, how do I tell httpd server that my Keycloak is running at *localhost:8080/auth*?**

Comment: You need to put keycloak adapter as frontend for you static server. Try to check out Keycloak Gatekeeper application.

Comment: It seems keycloak-gateway has been deprecated. Is there any other tool that we might use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc) that enables an Apache 2.x webserver to operate as an OpenID Connect Relying Party (RP) to an OpenID Connect Provider (OP). Using this we can secure any static website using any OpenID Connect Providers like Keycloak, etc.